# Spring boot data rest timestamp parse error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, retrofit, spring-data-rest

I am trying to do CRUD operation using data rest but after insert first record to the database I unable to retrieve the data from database as json

here is my code:

**Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ledger_group")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
public class LedgerGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "key_code")
    private Integer keyCode;

    @Column(name="ledger_group")
    private String ledgerGroupName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    private LedgerGroup parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<LedgerGroup> ledgerGroupList;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="timestamp_created")
    private Date timestampCreated;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="timestamp_modified")
    private Date timestampModified;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to LedgerAccount
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ledgerGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<LedgerAccount> ledgerAccounts;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @Column(name="user_created")
    private String createdBy;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @Column(name="user_modified")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    public LedgerGroup() {
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface LedgerGroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LedgerGroup, Integer> {
}
```

**Here is the error from browser**

[image]

Here is the error from console

```
2018-10-11 10:27:27.911  WARN 11122 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Invalid Object Id definition for com.icloud.micro.model.LedgerGroup: cannot find property with name 'id'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid Object Id definition for com.icloud.micro.model.LedgerGroup: cannot find property with name 'id' (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap["ledgerGroups"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]
```

Comment: please provide DB side id name. is this auto in DB side?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
```